# Android app that works as a Dialog window only

Tags: java, android, dialog, modal-dialog, window

I need to make an Android app that interacts with another. Like this: there is an app A, which calls app B. App B must be only a small window-dialog where data is entered, and when accepting it, the flow must be returned to app A.

I didn't find information about how to do this. Everything I find and try is about whole-window apps to which a Dialog can be added, but I can not find how to make an entire app that is just a small Dialog.

I'm a rookie on Android, they told me the version of Gradle they should be minSdkVersion 19.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to have an entirely separate app for a dialog. That's a very roundabout solution. If you need a popup data entry dialog, use [`AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs).

Comment: Hello! its because in my company we can't modify the first app. The company of the first app will make an intent to launch our app and we need to put some data and then send to their app. Its for security reasons, its a credit card payment app. How can i make and app with only a dialog? Thanks!